# uibCollapse nested in an directive element won't work,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I click my-dir, collapsed elements won't expand.
I have set size in css for `.btn` class to ensure actually click event.

// index.html

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <p>{{hello}}</p>
    <div class="btn" my-dir></div>
</body>
```

// app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.hello = 'hello';
});

app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: './tmpl.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.isCollapsed = true;
          element.bind('click', function (e) {
            scope.isCollapsed = !scope.isCollapsed;
          })
        }
    };
});
```

// tmpl.html

```
<div class="dir-box">
    <div uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Nice to meet You!</p>
        <p>: )</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why uibCollapse does not work in this situation ?

Any ideas ?

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TlLHgD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things that you need to fix:

1.Change `click` binding to `ng-click`. By default angular does not run its `$digest` cycle on jquery events. You can fix that by adding `$scope.$apply()` or `$timeout` in your code, but I recommend using `ng-click` as a more proper way.

`<div class="btn" my-dir ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"></div>`

By your original code I should add it inside your directive template, but your `dir-box` position does not overlap with the blue area...

2.Use `overflow:hidden` on `uib-collapse` element.

`<div uib-collapse="isCollapsed" style="overflow: hidden;">`

The contents were still showing when the parent height is 0

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HUaMnXtkzbNkzFQ9E9qh?p=preview)